# Transpile only with closure compiler

Tags: minify, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, transpiler

I use [Google Closure Compiler](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler) already for minifying my code.  As part of this, I am transpiling to `ECMASCRIPT5` (don't ask) with `--language_out ECMASCRIPT5`.

But so that I can see the raw (transpiled) code easily for debugging, I want the ability to transpile to `ECMASCRIPT5` only, without any minification.

I know that I can use `-O WHITESPACE_ONLY --language_out ECMASCRIPT5`, but that still lumps all the transpiled code onto a single line, which isn't great for readability when debugging.

Is there a way to transpile *only*, without any minification at all?

Comment: Not an answer but a suggestion: just format your code using a formatter as a next step. Not only will it be more readable, but it might also produce a more deterministic result.